# How to Count enabled CheckBoxList items checked using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple jQuery procedure running to make sure a user checks at least 1 checkbox.

```
var AllAppsCheck = $('#<%= FillInfo2.FindControl("AllAppsCheck").ClientID %> input:checked').length;

if (AllAppsCheck == 0 ) {
    alert("Please select atleast 1 role!");
    return false;
}
```

I would like to add to this code to count only the items in the checkboxlist which are enabled and to disregard items which are disabled.

Comment: Use `:enabled`. And please search the docs first. http://api.jquery.com

Comment: THX Luck Soni this worked great never knew it was that simple much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
if($('input[type="checkbox"]:enabled:checked').length) {
 // at least one checked
} else {
 // none checked
}
```

Comment: You could even do `:checkbox:enabled:checked`.

Comment: @BillCriswell $( ":checkbox" ) is equivalent to $( "[type=checkbox]" ) so yes of course :)

Comment: Just lettin' OP know.

Comment: A benefit of `[type=checkbox]` is that it maintains a fully valid Selectors API selector, so `querySelectorAll` will be used internally. IMO, it's good to stick to standards compliant selectors, so that the practice is transferable when using the native API.

Answer (score 0):

var AllAppsCheck = $('#<%= FillInfo2.FindControl("AllAppsCheck").ClientID %> input:checked:not(:disabled)').length;

Answer (score 0):

Use `:enabled` selector. You can read more information about `:enabled` over [here](http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/)

Try this,

```
     $('#yourID input:enabled:checked').length;
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fe3ME/)

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Fe7tG/4/

Select disabled inputs with

```
$('input:disabled')
```